# Moodle questionary

Tags: moodle

I'm using moodle 3.2 and I wonder if someone can help me with questionary activity.

I want to create like a rolplay in moodle using a quiz, in which the question or page a respondent sees next based on how they answer the current question.

Lets say if I have :
For question 1)
if user response

a) then move to question X
b) then move to question Y
c) then move to question X
d) then move to question H

Not sure how to achieve this.

Best Regards,
Thanks

Sebastian.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the lesson module in Moodle - https://docs.moodle.org/en/Lesson_module - that sounds like exactly what it does.

Comment: Yes, but lesson let me define that in buttons (is more a navegation thing ) , but I want to do it depending on the response of the user, and also in quiz not in lesson, cause I have in my backend some logic related only with quiz.
Thanks

Comment: There isn't any real way to achieve this with the quiz, that I know of. You *might* be able to hack something together with a custom question behaviour (but that is a little tenuous). I still think that the lesson is the best place for 'If a) then go to X, if b) then go to Y' behaviour ...